# AngularJS - Calling abstract state not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want use nested views in AngularJS 1.6, with UI-router.

I have 3 states, the first is an abstract view named settings, and the second and the third are two views.

```
.state('settings', {
    url: '/settings',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<ui-view />'
})
.state('settings.account', {
    url: '/account',
    templateUrl: './partials/settings/account.html',
    resolve: {
        loginRequired: loginRequired
    }
})
.state('settings.password', {
    url: '/password',
    templateUrl: './partials/settings/password.html',
    resolve: {
        loginRequired: loginRequired
    }
})
```

The problem is that nothing appears when I go to settings/account or settings/password...

Comment: does `/settings` route works fine,? any error in browser console?

Comment: I do not know why but actually, the route **/settings** does not work, I am redirected to the default page.

Comment: what is default page?, your setting page should be default one. can you make some plunker\fiddle?

Comment: What I would look for: 
- is the resolve resolved correctly?
- is the ``templateUrl`` correct?
- is the template empty?

Comment: There is a pastebin with my config code: https://pastebin.com/GELVu027